# How to split the user login error message between username and password?

Tags: users, form, login, error-templates

Hoping this is possible. I want to split the username and password error message to return it separately depending whether it is username or password that is incorrect and not just a the generic (Invalid username or password) message. How do I go about this? I don't require answers as to whether it is more secure or not just whether it is possible.

Cheers

Comment: Are you hoping to do this on the main craft login page or a custom form?

Comment: @AaronBerkowitz Custom form.

Comment: I don't believe there is a built-in way. If you take a look at the [`UserSessionService`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UserSessionService.php#L726), you'll see that messages are returned based on an error code. When a username and password combination fail, it triggers this single message to be returned.

Comment: @AaronBerkowitz hmmm looks like that is the default message and there is no code for just username or password error although on the registration form it does split the 2 input fields. I wonder if there is a way of extending this with a plugin?

Comment: Yeah, nothing's stopping you from making a plugin that provides it's own login implementation. @AaronBerkowitz - Mind adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in way. If you take a look at the [`UserSessionService`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UserSessionService.php#L726), you'll see that messages are returned based on an error code. When a username and password combination fail, it triggers this single message to be returned.